# How to create a simple Restful Web services in eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, rest

There is a problem with the web.xml file.
The web.xml file contains the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>JAX-RS-Starter</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

There is an error in `<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">`. The error message is:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Value '2.5' is not in the enumeration list.

It must be one of the following:
- 2.4

Code:
    - cvc-attribute.3: The value '2.5' of attribute 'version' on element 'web-app' is not valid with 
     respect to its type, 'web-app-versionType'.
```

There is another error in `<display-name>JAX-RS-Starter</display-name>`. The error message is:

```
Invalid element name:
- display-name

One of the following is expected:
- distributable
- context-param
- filter
- filter-mapping
- listener
- servlet
- servlet-mapping
- session-config
- mime-mapping
- welcome-file-list
- error-page
- jsp-config
- security-constraint
- login-config
- security-role
- message-destination
- locale-encoding-mapping-list

Error indicated by:
{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/
 j2ee}
with code:
```

How could I solve the problems?

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to the version 2.4 schema, using http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd, instead of the version 2.5 schema. It expects and only validates a value of 2.4. If you want to use a value of 2.5, use the 2.5 schema with http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd.